# SQL loop inserts

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, sql-insert

I have a company table with list of companies name and company id.

Now there is a `Value` table which hold information about the company with reference to company id.

I need to first get the list and size of the companies  and for all the companies insert a particular feature information in the `Value` table.

This means I need to have all companies having those features in the `Value` table.

I tried to use the below SQL which gives a compilation error. But the for loop works well without the insert.

```
DECLARE
  x NUMBER(2) ;
BEGIN 
    FOR x IN (select distinct company_num from company where comp_IN_comp='T') LOOP
       INSERT INTO VALUE (PROPERTY_NUM, DATA_GROUP, NUM_UPDATES, 
        CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, VALUE) VALUES 
        ('78', x ,'0', TO_DATE('2015-12-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
        'ADMIN', TO_DATE('2015-12-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'ADMIN', 'N');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Could you post the compile error?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? Please add a relevant tag - `oracle`, `sql-server`, `mysql`, `postgresql` - or whatever else you might be using

Comment: This Oracle 11g enterpise edition

Comment: Error:Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 174:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this - just use an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO VALUE (PROPERTY_NUM, 
                   DATA_GROUP, 
                   NUM_UPDATES, 
                   CREATED_DATE, 
                   CREATED_BY, 
                   LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
                   LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                   VALUE)
SELECT             DISTINCT '78',
                   company_num,
                   '0',
                   TO_DATE('2015-12-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                   'ADMIN',
                   TO_DATE('2015-12-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                   'ADMIN',
                   'N'
FROM               company
WHERE              comp_in_comp='T'
```

Comment: so , if there are 10 companies all the 10 companies will get the features added in the value table ?

Comment: This is the best way to do it but it's worth noting the original error was the the INSERT referenced `x` when it should have used `x.company_num`.  The cursor column must be referenced even if there's only one column.

Comment: So, I case if some of the rows already exist how do we update these rows.